# Aligning paragraphs inside rectangle

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to align paragraphs (center or right) inside rectangle boxes using css "text-align"
When the paragraph is small (one or two words) it does not align but when the paragraph is big, there is perfect alignment.

Here is my code / effort

```
//html
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

//css
p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
//javascript
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg") 
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

let text = [
  "WHO Coronavirus disease situation dashboard presents official daily counts of COVID-19",
  "Data Analysis",
  "Javascript",
  "Compare Performance of S&P 500 Index against other Indices"
];
let rect = svg
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", (d) => d)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

let texty = svg
  .selectAll("boxestext")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", (d) => d)
  .attr("class", "boxes")
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .attr("class", "mytext")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "mytext" + i)
  .style("font", 50)
  .html((d, i) => "<p>" + text[i] + "</p>");
```

Comment: Can you provide `HTML` snippet for this?

Comment: Here it goes
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

Comment: hm. Make sure you've set up your paragraphs to take 100% of the parent element's width.
Probably, <p> with 1-2 words just aren't equal to <p> with more content width-wise.
(try to add "width: 100%" to your css code)

Comment: Hi @Serhiy. I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi,@Zubair. Maybe, I didn't get your situation then, can you set up a demo on codepen?
It would help a lot. 

Another lucky gues: you can try to add left: 0; right: 0; to your CSS.

Comment: https://codepen.io/zubair57/pen/gOLpvgE

Comment: You can see that paragraphs "Data Analysis" and "JavaScript" are not in center of the rectangle/box

Comment: .mytext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228522/discussion-between-serhiy-and-zubair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working answer from the comments:

```js
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg") 
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

let text = [
  "WHO Coronavirus disease situation dashboard presents official daily counts of COVID-19",
  "Data Analysis",
  "Javascript",
  "Compare Performance of S&P 500 Index against other Indices"
];

let rect = svg
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", (d) => d)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

let texty = svg
  .selectAll("boxestext")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", (d) => d)
  .attr("class", "boxes")
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .attr("class", "mytext")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "mytext" + i)
  .style("font", 50)
  .html((d, i) => "<p>" + text[i] + "</p>");
```

```css
.mytext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```